# How to create API to check application on real Android device

Tags: java, android

Could anyone help me? I am storing data in my local server and using API like http://10.0.2.2/file.php its working fine when I run the application on emulator but when I run the same application on the real Android device it gives error in the android studio:

> Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2

I tried with 127.0.0.1 but it also gives error in the android studio:

> Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1

Finally, I tried with my API address like HTTP:/192.168.0.100/file.php but it's not working it's giving same error. Please help me. How can I make API correct which can run on the real device also?

**Here is my Java code:**

```
private  static final String TOKEN_URL="http://10.0.2.2/insertdata.php";<br>
StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,TOKEN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Token Stored Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error pop uo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: "+error.getMessage());

                }
            }){

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String >params=new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("tokenr",SharedPrefManager.getMsharepref(getApplicationContext()).getToken());
                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Token not generated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: is your laptop and mobile connected to same connection?

Comment: yes I am using same wifi on both devices

Comment: can you check whether it works on your mobile browser?

Comment: yes its not working on my mobile device I am writing my IP address on my mobile browser but it's not working it says this site is not reachable or can't connect

Comment: can you post some code where you are hitting the url in your app.

Comment: yes please see the code which I have uploaded

Comment: I think you need to cross check your ip address once again. Nothing wrong I can find.

Comment: I have checked multiple times. I spend almost half day on this issue this is working fine on emulator but not on android real device

Comment: why my pc IP address  is not working on my android real device. I put my IP address on my android real device browser its not working it says this site can not be reached.

Comment: @MajidAli sounds like a networking issue to me.  Are you able to get it to work on another device on the same Wi-Fi? (IE a browser not on the API server).